# Java Pack200 library output different from command line tool output

Tags: java, jar, compression

I'm dealing with some gzipped pack200 files and have no trouble unpacking them with the command line tool. I only run into problems when I attempt to unpack the files with the pack200 library.

For reference, this is the method I am using to unpack the files:

```
//Output from this can be properly unpacked with command line tool
InputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));

//This is where things go awry
Pack200.Unpacker unpacker = Pack200.newUnpacker();
JarOutputStream out = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.jar"));
unpacker.unpack(in, out);
```

Here is the output of unpacker.properties():

```
com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.default.timezone: false
com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.disable.native: false
com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.verbose: 0
pack.class.attribute.CompilationID: RUH
pack.class.attribute.SourceID: RUH
pack.code.attribute.CharacterRangeTable: NH[PHPOHIIH]
pack.code.attribute.CoverageTable: NH[PHHII]
pack.deflate.hint: keep
pack.effort: 5
pack.keep.file.order: true
pack.modification.time: keep
pack.segment.limit: -1
pack.unknown.attribute: pass
```

Some other relevant information:

- The jar files output by the library are consistently smaller than those unpacked by the command line tool.
- The library generated files use a newer version of the .zip format (0x14 vs 0x0A).
- unpack200.exe version 1.30, 07/05/05
- jdk version 1.7.0_21

So to reiterate, the jar files generated by the command line tool function properly while those generated by the library do not.

I very much appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: You aren't closing the output. The necessity for this is specifically mentioned in the Javadoc for `Pack200`, and you should always close `OutputStreams` and `Writers` in any case.

Comment: @EJP Yeah, I determined that. A rather stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was something very simple, but I'm happy to have found the problem. Here is the solution I was able to use:

```
//Output from this can be properly unpacked with command line tool
InputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));

//This is where things go awry
Pack200.Unpacker unpacker = Pack200.newUnpacker();
JarOutputStream out = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.jar"));
unpacker.unpack(in, out);
out.close();
```

Don't forget your `JarOutPutStream.close();`, kids.